# A direct link to my Facebook review page doesn't load it on mobile (it simply opens the fb app)

Tags: facebook, email, links, mobile

If I send a link to `https://www.facebook.com/[COMPANYNAME]/reviews`, it works perfectly for people on desktop, but not at all for those on mobile, it just opens the Facebook app and they're not redirected to my specific review page.

Any idea on how to send mobile users directly to the specific page?
I want to be able to send the link by email.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook has replaced reviews with recommendations (https://starfish.reviews/what-facebooks-switch-from-reviews-to-recommendations-means-for-your-business/)

I also have not (yet) found a way to leave a recommendation on a mobile browser. I believe it's not possible.

Not an answer, but a clue: we have the same problem, and some of our competitors have the same problem, but for some pages (e.g. https://www.facebook.com/Perfume-24h-105571215696977/reviews), the link lands on the review page... but I can't leave a review on mobile....

I tried changing the name of the page, but I'm still not able to land on the review page.

I would recommend replacing Facebook review links with Google review links, or the like.